# Uint and uintptr in golang

Tags: go, types, uint

I know `uintptr` follow same rules for its size with `uint` in Go;
I guess `uint` and `uintptr` are the same and only they are different in the use case. so why `uintptr` is not an alias for `uint` in go built-ins like how byte is an alias for `uint8` and `rune` for `int32`?

Comment: integer and pointer sizes are not guaranteed to be equal.

Answer (score 3):

From the Go [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types), here is how the sizes of the "unsized" integer data types are defined:

> uint     either 32 or 64 bits
>
> int      same size as uint
>
> uintptr  an unsigned integer large enough to store the uninterpreted bits of a pointer value

As you can see, both types have a *distinct* size definition. Even if they are coincidentally the same size on most (?) platforms, there's no language-level reason why these types should be conflated.

There's also the benefit of having a distinct type for pointer integers: as Go has strict typing, you cannot use a `uintptr` as any other int type without converting it first. This is important because `uintptr` is primarily used for `unsafe` purposes in Go, so having a distinct type gives strong indications or errors when you might be misusing unsafe features (or at least, it will make you think twice about it).